# MySQL query to get count of only new users each day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of call records, 
I need to know for each day how many people are first time calling every day,

Note: they called the selected day, but never before that day.
I managed to have this working.

```
SELECT * FROM call_history GROUP BY caller_id HAVING SUBSTR(MIN(call_date), 1, 10) = SUBSTR(NOW(), 1, 10)
```

This query gives me all the people who called today (or any date I put in instead of NOW) but never called before,
I need to find a way to get the results for all days in a single query and not ask day by day,

result should be like that:

```
2013-01-01, 10 new callers
2013-01-01, 15 new callers
2013-01-01, 22 new callers
2013-01-01, 4 new callers
```

and so on....

Thank you!

Comment: what is your table structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will perform best for what you're looking for.

The inner query gets the first call date by caller, and the outer query groups them into callers per call date.

```
SELECT first_call_date, COUNT(caller_id) AS caller_count
FROM (
    SELECT caller_id, DATE(MIN(call_date)) AS first_call_date
    FROM call_history 
    GROUP BY caller_id
) AS ch
GROUP BY first_call_date
```

Comment: I gave +1, but caller_id is not needed in select list of sub-query. Then again, I don't think it does any harm either.

Comment: @dbenham - Very true, it could just be done with first_call_date and COUNT(*), but I think the answer is a little clearer as is.  Might be a little confusing as to what you're trying to do otherwise.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT c1.call_date,
       count(caller_id)
FROM call_history c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT ID
     FROM call_history c2
     WHERE c2.call_date<c1.call_date and c2.caller_id=c1.caller_id)
GROUP BY c1.call_date
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I don't think it'll work for the OP, because it looks like `call_date` is not a `date`, but a `datetime` column, with multiple calls possible per caller per day (note how he's comparing them in his query).  You may want to tweak your answer to account for that.